# The original parameter passed to another screen

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter and trying to figure out why passing a List to another screen via Navigator modifies the original list.

What I need is to not modify the homePageList when decrementing from _otherScreenList on the next screen.

I've made an example that demonstrates what is happening.
The homePageList is being modified even though I am only making a change to _otherScreenList.

Click the FAB plus button to add to the homePageList, then click Next Screen. Then click the FAB minus button and it modifies widget.passedInList as well as the previous screen homePageList.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<String> homePageList = List();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
      homePageList.add('A' + _counter.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'homePageList',
            ),
            Text(
              '$homePageList',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            FlatButton(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text('Next Screen'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => OtherScreen(
                      passedInList: homePageList,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OtherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  OtherScreen({Key key, this.passedInList}) : super(key: key);

  final List<String> passedInList;

  @override
  _OtherScreenState createState() => _OtherScreenState();
}

class _OtherScreenState extends State<OtherScreen> {
  List<String> _otherScreenList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _otherScreenList = widget.passedInList;
  }

  void _removeLast() {
    setState(() {
      // only remove from _otherScreenList, but it still removes from the widget.passedInList
      _otherScreenList.removeLast();
      print('widget.passedInList: ' + widget.passedInList.toString());
      print('_otherScreenList: ' + _otherScreenList.toString());
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Other Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'widget.passedInList',
            ),
            Text(
              '${widget.passedInList}',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
            Text(
              'otherScreenList',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_otherScreenList',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _removeLast,
        tooltip: 'Remove last',
        child: Icon(Icons.minimize),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior makes sense since you are passing a reference to a list.

However, you would like `homePageList` and `otherPageList` to be two different lists, such that `otherPageList` is initialized with the values of `homePageList`.

A way of cloning a list is using `List.from`:

```dart
class _OtherScreenState extends State<OtherScreen> {
  List<String> _otherScreenList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _otherScreenList = List<String>.from(widget.passedInList);
  }

  // ...
```

And this will now work as you expect. Here you can run it: https://dartpad.dev/embed-flutter.html?id=a9f55b6de67133a9d686b389ad07da22&theme=dark

You wouldn't need to do this with `String`, `int`, `bool`, etc as Dart will consider them "primitives" (even though they are real objects) and pass them by value into methods and constructors, instead of by reference which is definitely the case for more complex data structures such as `List`.